# Amazon S3 HTTPS not loading with Chrome and wget on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, wget

I am having a problem downloading files from Amazon S3 via HTTPS on Chrome (Ubuntu Linux). The URLs download without issue on versions of chrome for other operating systems. It loads fine on Firefox for Linux.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/moteevate-transloadit/a8/f5175e0facd88377aef46369d543c0/dc74257ea7ee32331debad0e6d5ae27d.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=0YSXSY8MWY6RRKGKTWG2&Expires=1686646438&Signature=C0WCeGKCGbU3OAxkrFq6kmkBCT0%3D

When the URL is changed to HTTP, it loads without issue. When I use wget, I get a message "403 forbidden" and it hangs indefinitely. Chrome also hangs indefinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works here in Ubutnu Linux with Chromium and with wget.

It only works in wget if you put " " around the URL, which contains special characters.  Otherwise I do get 403 forbidden.  I receive a jpeg file, 5.1k. It looks like the same drawing I get on chromium. The URL produces a picture of some kind of rough drawing with black lines.

wget version is 1.13.4

chromium about:

```
Chromium    25.0.1364.160 (Developer Build
25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.12.10.1) Ubuntu 12.10 OS Linux  WebKit   537.22 (trunk@137939) JavaScript    V8 3.15.11.16 Flash 11.2 r202 User Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22 Command Line     /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser
--flag-switches-begin --sync-keystore-encryption --flag-switches-end Executable Path    /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser Profile Path /home/pb/.config/chromium/Default Variations    b03ddc1f-2d9ef0cc f9b252d0-fd526c81 ca6785ad-766fa2d 3709139-766fa2d 977e9dfe-766fa2d 7f6da4bf-37924bda 75f7fb7e-611a9f49 262f996f-eeefeb17 24dca50e-455c9cca 3028188e-b9bbd1b6 246fb659-a90023b1 f296190c-f911fcfa 4442aae2-a90023b1 75f0f0a0-4ad60575 e2b18481-cdc3d902 e7e71889-4ad60575
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I translate this to get a URL that will work for me in Chrome (27.0). I think it may be a separate issue unrelated to the wget problem.